# How do I restrict a method so that it will only run on certain days if called?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I want to restrict a method to only be executable on weekdays. Is there a spring annotation that would allow for this? Im trying to avoid writing a method that just checks the day of the week and exits.

Comment: *"I'm trying to avoid writing a method that just checks the day of the week and exits."* - 1) Why?  Nothing wrong with doing that.  2) I think you are out of luck.   This would be "rarely used" functionality.  The kind of thing that is not worth the Spring team implementing and maintaining.

Comment: I was worried about that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's any comment to check the day of the week in the spring.

You may need to use the following methods:

```
public void checkDate() {
    
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
    
    DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = localDate.getDayOfWeek();
    
    if(dayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY || dayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY) {
        // ...do something
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is what i was thinking as well. Good to know that im just overthinking. I appreciate your response